# Dojo Grid CheckBox Cannot be clicked

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dojo, dojox.grid, jsonreststore

I am trying to make a Dojo Grid with checkbox (multiple columns are checkbox) and I am trying to make them alwaysEditing.

I used type = dojox.grid.cells.Bool but I think it does not allow me to click the checkbox, I tried to see what happens on the http request and it seems to send undefined parameters each time i click on the checkbox. I am not sure how to add other method in the JsonRestStore, is there any other method that is needed?

Here is the code:

```
require([
    "dojox/grid/DataGrid",
    "dojo/store/JsonRest",
    "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
    "dijit/form/Form",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(DataGrid,JsonRestStore,ObjectStore,dijitForm, request){
    SalesFormGridStore = new JsonRestStore({target:"/sales/SalesForm/DataRequestedDojoGrid/", idProperty: "OrderNo"});
    SalesFormGridDataStore = new ObjectStore({objectStore: SalesFormGridStore});
    SalesFormGridStructure = {
        cells: [
            // Column definitions start...
            { 
                name: 'Delivery?', 
                field: 'DeliveryFlag', 
                width: '40px', 
                styles: 'text-align: center;', 
                editable: true, 
                alwaysEditing: true, 
                type: dojox.grid.cells.Bool, 
                editor: dojox.grid.cells.CheckBox
            } 
            // Column definitions end....
        ]
    };
    SalesFormGridGrid = new DataGrid({
        store: SalesFormGridDataStore,
        structure : SalesFormGridStructure,
    }, "SalesFormGrid");
    SalesFormGridGrid.startup();
});
```

When the form loads or if you scroll outside the range, it request a normal query.

```
/sales/SalesForm/DataRequestedDojoGrid/
```

But when I click on the checkbox, it does not allow me to click it and it just request the following request.

```
/sales/SalesForm/DataRequestedDojoGrid/1

/sales/SalesForm/DataRequestedDojoGrid/2
```

Would I need to wire the click event manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow got the answer.

I just followed the example of the codeproject tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/650443/).

Basically, I used a memory store and cache store object. Before I just directly link the json store to the object store.

```
SalesFormGridMemoryStore = new MemoryStore({ idProperty: "SalesNo" });
SalesFormGridJsonStore = new JsonRestStore({target:"/sales/SalesForm/DataRequestedDojoGrid/", idProperty: "SalesNo"});
SalesFormGridCacheStore = new CacheStore(SalesFormGridJsonStore, SalesFormGridMemoryStore);
SalesFormGridObjectStore = new ObjectStore({objectStore: SalesFormGridCacheStore});
```

Since there is no cache and memory store before, all edit needs to be directly send to the master store which is the json store.

Hope this helps somebody.